# Grails - createCriteria: associations + not + ilike

Tags: grails, createcriteria

some how a Criteria: associations + not + ilike does not give a good result.
I still get cases with actions that have the status I don't want in the result.
Any clue or suggestion for other approaches?

I have this in controller:

```
def pgp = [:]
pgp.max = params.max?.toInteger() ?: 20;
pgp.offset = params.offset?.toInteger() ?: 0
pgp.max = 20;
def result = Case.createCriteria().list(pgp) {
        actions {
            not {
                and {
                    ilike("status","%CLOSED")
                    ilike("status","%Installed in PRD")
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This is the relevant Domain snipped:

```
class Case {

String caseCode
String caseName
String caseType

static hasMany = [ actions : Action ]
```

I'm on Grails 2.4.4

Comment: I didn't understand what your problem was

Comment: The issue is that I get a result with all cases. As no criteria have been applied.

Comment: what if you leave only 1 `ilike` in your criteria? would it work?

Comment: well partly. It gives cases that have at least one actions with that status. Is it possibl eto get cases that only have actions with this status? (All other cases are not complete)

Comment: give some examples, otherwise I can only speculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Boolean logic is faulty - the `and` should be an `or`.  Your current tests will be true for *every* possible value of `status`, as any value that passes `ilike("status","%CLOSED")` will fail `ilike("status","%Installed in PRD")` and vice versa.

Comment: True. Changed to or and now I get a list of open cases! Too simple! Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why I get cases listed more than once?

Comment: @BioBier try `listDistinct` instead of `list`